# level shifter alternatives using passives

Tags: level-shifting

I have always used level translators when communicating between 2 systems(or controllers) of different voltage levels. For eg txb0108 is a commonly used one, among a host of others.
Now, why should one use such an ASIC. Why can the same be not done using a voltage dividor or such a simple and cheap component ? What is the major game changing advantage when we use such dedicated ASICs ?
Ofcourse, these ASICs might come power packed with buffers and such facilities, but if it was a straighforward voltage level lowering can the resistors suffice ?

Comment: If you know what load to drive and how it affects signal integrity, you might be able to get away with a divider, but in most cases you either don't know or the signal integrity crapsout.

Comment: could you kindly explain please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Why can the same be not done using a voltage dividor or..."

Because a voltage divider consisting of 2 resistors:

- can only interface between a higher voltage to a lower voltage, for example: 3.3 V to 1.8 V
- the divider forms a resistive load, when a signal is 1 a current flows. This is unacceptable for low power applications.
- it only works properly at the input/output voltage ratio it is designed for
  so a divider for 3.3 V to 1.8 V might not work for 3.3 V to 2.2 V
- The impedance level of the output signal increases because it comes through a resistor, not from a low impedance output. This is problematic for high frequency signals.

Proper levelshifters don't suffer from these disadvantages.

So in general: no, a resistive divider cannot replace a proper levelshifter.
Maybe in some applications it can but be prepared for all the disadvantages listed above. Is is worth that ? I would say no and just use a levelshifter.

Comment: True. To be more precise, an other similar divider can be made for 3.3 to 2.2 Volts too, but resistor values have to be changed.

Answer (score 4):

This is my favorite simple levels shifter circuit. It's bidirectional and everything.
[image]

The only real downside is a semi decent driver is required, a weak one won't cut it.

Comment: The thing is that he wants passives, not just discretes. So what this question really needs as an answer is a tuturial on signal integrity.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff Bidirectional level shifting is not possible with only passive components. To directly replace the txb0108 at least one discrete is required.

Comment: Alas it's unclear from the question if he even wants bidirectional...

Comment: yes I get your point. But suppose I need to merely step down a voltage then, can I not do it using a voltage divider ?

Comment: Not bidirectional. Just uni directional.

Answer (score 1):

Eh, unidrectional high-to-low can be done  with resistors and diodes https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/3007

[image]

Comment: This of course suffers from all the problems listed in @FakeMoustache's answer. And I'm not going into more details, because I found we have another question on this in-line resistor solution http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21055/voltage-level-shifting