# SIM900 schematic verification

Tags: circuit-design, sim900

I am designing a `SIM900` schematic so before going further I thought of verifying the schematic first. I will using `SIM900` with `PIC18F2520`. So to power the `SIM900` and Microcontroller, I am using `LM7805` for MCU and `LM2576` for `SIM900`. Following is the circuit:

[image]

`LM2576` o/p `4.1v` is for `SIM900` & `LM7805` o/p `5v` is for MCU

**SIM900 Circuit:**

[image]

Explanation:

**PWRKEY**: PWRKEY is connected with a push button which when pressed will connect this pin to ground, in order to start the power on scenario of module.

**UART**: TX RX lines are connected to RX TX of the MCU.

**NRESET**: connected to a push button to reset the module.

**VRTC**: I am not using any RTC function so just connected a `4.7uF` cap.

**NET & STATUS**: Connected led's to these pins to show the status and network of the module.

Apart from the above schematic, is there any recommended circuit which I am missing in the circuit.?

Do I need a voltage level shifter between TX RX of `SIM900` and TX RX of MCU.? I initially used a breakout board of SIM900 and tested it with the MCU, it was working fine without any external circuitry for voltage level shifter.

Is there anything which I am missing in the circuit. Any suggestions would be very helpful.

[Breakout board](https://www.robomart.com/gsm-module/gsm-gprs-sim900a-module-with-stub-antenna-and-sma-connector):
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SIM900 Serial interface runs on 2.8 V logic levels, PIC runs on 5 V so you are definitely need level shifting. You did not provide a link to that break-out board but I am sure that there must be some level conversion circuit on that.

From [application note](http://www.puntoflotante.net/SIM900-POWER-SUPPLY-DESIGN.pdf).

> Please note that the UART level is 2.8V, if the level is not matching, a level shift circuit is needed.

Comment: Can you give me a link for that circuit

Comment: There are plenty of them on this site, do a search please.

Comment: @SAndrew I have used dedicated ICs but simple circuits with some MOSFET will do the work.

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely use level shifting. But actually when I did this on breadboard using breakout, I didnt used any level shifting and thats why I got confused. I have added a link to that breakout in question.

Comment: Hey I studied about the level shifting and I found out that its not that much complex. I found this [document](http://simcom.ee/documents/SIM900/SIM900_Serial%20Port_Application%20Note_V1.03.pdf) page 7 where they have described level shifting using transistor which looks best for this problem. Also found this [link](http://www.edaboard.com/thread327975.html) where they have discussed that using [voltage divider](http://www.edaboard.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=112109) circuit is also enough. Which one should I go with.?

Comment: You can try this IC: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txb0104.pdf

Comment: This alternative is also fine and simple: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/196466/123923

Comment: @SAndrew Yes, it is the cheapest and easiest way to go with transistors. Also unfortunately the supplier of the breakout board does not include schematic so I could not check the level shifter. But I am sure that there is one, probably they go with transistors as well.

Comment: @AdamCalvetBohl Thanks that IC is also best for this. But unfortunately its not available near by me so I'll go with transistor solution.

Comment: @BenceKaulics Apart from the level shifter, is my power circuit design good for this purpose as I am using two regulators, one for MCU and one for SIM900. What other things I need to keep in mind while designing its board layout.